# What's the VHDL equivalent of C++11 nullptr?

Tags: vhdl

What's the VHDL equivalent of C++11 pointer assignment to nullptr?  Here's my VHDL example:

```
    process 
        type MyLine is access string;
        variable MyLine1 : MyLine;
    begin
        MyLine1 := new string(1 to 40);
        deallocate(MyLine1);
        MyLine1 := nullptr; --???  Doesn't work: how to set it back to null pointer?
        wait;
   end process;
```

Comment: as a side note - VHDL already has a string access type declared in `std.textio` called `line`

Comment: Why do you want to set `MyLine1` to null?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do:

```
...
MyLine1 := null;
...
```

Note that `deallocate` assigns `MyLine1` with `null` when it releases the data structure, to avoid that it is used afterwards, so it is unnecessary to do any additional explicit assign.

Comment: VHDL versions previous to VHDL 2019 have no garbage collection, so simply assigning an access type object to null can cause dangling pointers and memory leaks.

Comment: that's good to know!

Comment: "NOTE 2—An implementation may (but need not) deallocate the storage occupied by an object created by an allocator, once this object has become inaccessible." VHDL versions before 2019 have no ***mandatory*** garbage collection. You'd expect that would follow the use multi-language support requirements. I wouldn't hold my breath for Vivado Simulator. You'd also expect standard defined TEXTIO read and write procedures would do it right. The question is what happens when copying access values outside those.

Comment: @user16145658 That would tie with Mentor confirming to me in a ticket they did GC, and  aldec having their `-accessleakreport` flag, which is removed in v12 in favor of GC for all VHDL versions.

Comment: The -2019 9.3.7 Allocators "Deallocation may be delayed by the implementation." is [non-deterministic](https://coderedirect.com/questions/623537/why-has-ada-no-garbage-collector) (Why has Ada no garbage collector? applicable to VHDL, read it all). VASG ought to make it deterministic in -202X. Objects of access types that are block, process, package body, or protected type body, declarative items and not associated with ports or parameters don't get garbage collected, everything else does, immediately as if allocated on stack instead of heap, equivalent to Modelsim SV 'after every step'.

Comment: Jim had mentioned the method in [Dangling reference detection and garbage collection during hardware simulation](https://patents.google.com/patent/US7403961), USUS7403961, but that has another 2 1/2 years to go on the patent. I think this is overkill. I've mentioned my method previously. The standard should disclose any essential patents VASG is aware of (or publicly disclose any method proposed in sufficient detail to implement to prevent first to file patenting.

Comment: @user16145658   If you would like to enter it as a VASG issue, do it here:  https://gitlab.com/IEEE-P1076/VHDL-Issues/-/issues.

Comment: @user16145658   The current wording is what EDA vendors asked for.   They want to be able to do garbage collection in a means that is efficient for simulation.   Why do I care how they do the deallocation - as long as they do it in a way that does not slow my simulation.

Comment: @Jim How about an entry in Annex D to not rely on the timing of garbage collection? It's not considered portable under "b) The time-variant state of all signals and variables in the description are the same at all times during the simulation, ..." when delayed, that darned determinism. With no vendor participation in the standardization process for the last two revisions that [requested change](http://www.eda-twiki.org/cgi-bin/view.cgi/P1076/GarbageCollection?raw=on&rev=2) to the standard was conveyed by an individual contributor (who worked for an "EDA vendor").

Comment: @user16145658   The non-determinism mentioned in the article you referenced is about execution speed and not program correctness.   An object that is a candidate for GC is by nature not referenced by anything, and hence, not part of the state of an variable in a simulation.    If you would like to explain your concerns, please do so on the issues page I referenced above.    1076-2019 was largely user driven.   1076-2008 LCS's were primarily written by contributors who also worked for EDA vendors.